# Beamed half note

Tags: piano

How can I play this sheet?
What that beamed half note means?

[image: From Czerny]

Comment: The stated duplicate is probably not the closest match, but we have a meta answer collection the multi-voice issues [here](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/new-tag-for-multiple-voices-issue-helpful).

Comment: The dotted half note isn't beamed, its stem is _down_, "overlapping" an eighth note with stem up.

Answer (score 3):

The half note, with it’s stalk pointing down, isn’t beamed. Its head just coincides with the first of a group of six 8th notes in the upper voice.  The two noteheads could have been written side by side, sometimes we notate them this way, with the black notehead hidden behind the open one.  The two ‘voices’ indicate a musical intent rather than something that can be literally played on a keyboard.  Hit the note once!

This is the alternative notation.  But then, I guess you'd be asking whether to play the note twice!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The beamed half note just means you press and hold that key with one finger while you play the eighth notes with two other fingers.  It even tells you which finger to use to hold the dotted half note down. in the second and third full measures.